# inexplicable change in value while using pointer typecasting

Tags: c, pointers, typecasting-operator

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main( void )
{ 
    int num = 1;
    char *b;

    b = (char*) &num;
    *(++b) = 2;
    printf("%d\n",num);

    return 0; 
}
```

> **Explanation :** When I compiled this code , I encountered "513" as an output.When I use a comment line for that line:
>   `*(++b)=2;

`Output converts into "1".`

> **Question 1:** Why did I encounter "513" as an output ?
>
> **Question 1:** Why did output change when use comment line that I implied ?

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: I expected that there cannot be any changing for value of num while using comment line.Because I did not change its value.

Comment: The value didn't change when you commented out the line, you are setting `num` to `1` in the initialization - I don't understand where you are observing a value change

Comment: I figured out what is happening , it's not necessary anymore , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that an `int` is 32 bit with little endian byte ordering on your system, the representation of `num` is `0x00000001` and looks like this in memory:

```
-----------------
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
-----------------
```

Then you point `b` to `num`:

```
  b
  |
  v
-----------------
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
-----------------
```

Then you do `*(++b)=2;`, it increments `b`, dereferences the incremented pointer, and writes 2 to that location.  So you now have.

```
      b
      |
      v
-----------------
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
-----------------
```

So now the representation of `num` is 0x00000201` which is 513 in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that on your machine, chars are byte-sized. That is why you are seeing this completely normal behavior.

Your num variable looks like this in memory.

0x00000001

You take address of it, treat it as a char* then set second char to 2 so now your num becomes.

0x00000201

When you convert that back to decimal, it correctly outputs 513.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int num=1;
```

represented in `32 bit` system as below

```
     0x103      0x102       0x101       0x100  (let's assume base address of num 0x100)
  -----------------------------------------------
 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0001 |
  -----------------------------------------------
                                                num
MSB                                          <--LSB
```

And here

```
char *b; /* char pointer i.e at a time points to 1 byte */
b=(char*)&num; /* b points to &num i.e 0x100 in above diagram */
```

it looks like

```
    0x103      0x102       0x101       0x100  
  -----------------------------------------------
 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0001 |
  -----------------------------------------------
                                                num
                                                 b <-- b points here
```

Now when this

```
*(++b)=2;
```

gets executed, first `++b` happens that means char pointer `b` gets incremented by one byte i.e it points to `0x101` location and then content of only `0x101` location assigned by `2`. It looks like

```
     0x103      0x102       0x101       0x100  
  -----------------------------------------------
 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0010 | 0000 0001 |
  -----------------------------------------------
                                     |          num
                                     b <-- b points to 0x101
```

Now when you print `num` it prints `512 + 1` which is `513`. I hope it clears your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

> When I compiled this code , I encountered "513" as an output.

You are getting this output because of this statement:

```
*(++b)=2;
```

Initially, `b` is pointing to `num`. Statement `*(++b)=2` will first increment the pointer `b` and point to next byte and then dereferencing it and assigning `2`.
Assuming on your platform `int` is `32` bit then:

```
initially
num = 1

00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001


num after this statement
*(++b)=2;

00000000 00000000 00000010 00000001

which is the binary representation of `513`.
```

> When I use a comment line for that line: `*(++b)=2;` Output converts into "1".

Of course, you have initialized `num` with `1` and what else you expect when printing `num` without making any change to it.